# Currency exchange besides banks in Nakhon Pathom, Thailand?

Tags: money, thailand, exchange

We've arrived in Nakhon Pathom, Thailand after the banks are closed and would really like to exchange our left over Malaysian ringgit for Thai baht.

I've walked all around the area around the Phra Pathom Chedi and the train station and banks seem to close as early as 3.30pm and I couldn't spot any money changers at all.

Is there a non-bank place to buy baht in this city?

(Yes of course I realize I can go to an ATM but for reasons that will just bloat the question and drift off my topic I'd appreciate answers only about exchange please.)

Comment: Some (higher end) hotels may offer currency exchange services. I.e. a quick Google shows that Sampran Riverside has an on-site currency exchange and looks reasonably centrally located (a few more hits seem a little further out). Not sure about the rates you'd get there, but might be worth a shot if you're really keen.

Comment: @MH.: It turns out that [Riverside is 22km away from the town centre](https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=Phetkasem+Frontage+Rd,+Tambon+Sanam+Chan,+Amphoe+Mueang+Nakhon+Pathom,+Chang+Wat+Nakhon+Pathom+73000,+Thailand&daddr=Sampran+Riverside,+Sampran+Riverside,+Pet+Kasem+Road,+Yaicha,+Sampran,+Nakhon+Pathom+73110,+Thailand&hl=en&geocode=Fbas0gAdKJ32BSmnAP4b2uXiMDG8FdjtjyerJA%3BFRea0QAd05X5BSndIUyh3OriMDE0BhG36ib4fQ&sll=13.832079,100.450401&sspn=0.159682,0.220757&vpsrc=0&mra=pr&ie=UTF8&t=m&z=12).

Comment: Right, sorry, I didn't spend much time looking closely at distances. My main point was that some hotels will offer currency exchange services. I figured your Googling skills are as good as mine when it comes to finding a specific place. :)

Comment: I tried a bunch of Google Maps searches for forex, exchange, etc and they only found stuff far away.

Comment: I would assume that on top of finding a location, there will be an issue of finding one that accepts Ringgit and not only USD and other more common currencies for that area.

Comment: @uncovery: In fact when the banks opened this morning I went to two and the exchange rate was so dismal I didn't change any money. It would've cost me $20 to change about $200 worth of ringgit to baht!

Answer (score 3):

Nahkon Pathom is not exactly a hotbed of tourism.  While a fair number Thai tourists visit, foreign visitors are a small minority.  And without foreign tourist traffic, there is not much demand for exchange services.  About your only choices will be banks and a few hotels (which you likely have discovered already).